# Close button for an expanding div

Tags: javascript, gsap, codepen

I am trying to include a close button for closing the expanded div to its original state. Right now in both examples below, you can click anywhere to close it which I want to disable.

Solutions for any of the two below would be great.

Thanks!

[First CodePen](https://codepen.io/ApoorvArv/pen/NYvQZG)

```
https://github.com/colinlohner/FSM-JS
```

[Second CodePen](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/WwgQEV)

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.3/TweenMax.min.js
```

Comment: For reference, this was answered [on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/22316-div-expanding-to-full-screen-with-a-close-button/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a closing button and attach the click event listener to the closing button instead of the expanded div.

In the first pen, lets say your closing button has the id `closing-button`. You'll have to replace

```
$fsmActual.addEventListener("click", closeFSM);
```

with

```
document.querySelector('#closing-button')
```

The second one has an closing function per div, so you'll need a closing button per div. Try this:

```
[...]
var tiles = document.querySelectorAll(".tile");
var closing = document.querySelectorAll(".closing-button");

for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {  
  addListeners(tiles[i], pages[i], closing[i]);
}

function addListeners(tile, page, close) { 

  tile.addEventListener("click", function() {
    animateHero(tile, page);
  });

  close.addEventListener("click", function() {
    animateHero(page, tile);
  });
```

Comment: Hey @Swimmer! Thanks for your answer. Let's say I have a close button with the class `close-button`, how can I attach the click even listener to it? What would the code be in that case?

_So sorry if my question seems stupid, I am quite new to coding and this is really advanced for me._

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Swimmer — thanks once again! I am sure lots of people would be able to fix it after your answers but I can't make it work for some reason. I am really sorry about that. Would you be able to create a pen on CodePen if it's not so much trouble for you? Maybe for the first example this one would be easier or more helpful: https://codepen.io/dedog/pen/dyPWePK

Comment: can you make a pen that actually has a closing button?

Comment: Sure, it is here: https://codepen.io/dedog/pen/ZEYKMQL

It is not styled though and is not showing up on the expanded div at the moment.

Comment: Also, I might be able to make it work if I would be able to place the code for the second one in the right place (or if I am replacing it with something). Would you be able to tell me where that code goes and if I should also take something out when I put it in?

Comment: Also, don't worry, your question isn't stupid - though I have to admit that it is somewhat basic. I suggest that you go read the details on a tutorial site like https://www.w3schools.com/ when you have the time - the relevant chapter for this question is JavaScript > [DOM Event Listener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Comment: Thanks so much Swimmer for the pen and the recommendation! I will take a look at it now and will also check out the tutorial at W3Schools :-)